# Numpy multiplication and create new list B[i] = Product(A[j]) where j =! i

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Create a one dimensional array B, where B[i] is the product of all A[j] where j != i.

For example: If A = {2, 1, 5, 9}, then B would be {45, 90, 18, 10}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way for `A` as an array -

```
In [59]: A2D = np.repeat(A[None],len(A),axis=0)

In [60]: np.fill_diagonal(A2D,1)

In [61]: A2D.prod(1)
Out[61]: array([45, 90, 18, 10])
```

Or with `np.prod` -

```
In [71]: A.prod()/A
Out[71]: array([45., 90., 18., 10.])
```

Or with `masking` -

```
In [85]: mask = ~np.eye(len(A),dtype=bool)

In [86]: np.broadcast_to(A,mask.shape)[mask].reshape(len(A),-1).prod(1)
Out[86]: array([45, 90, 18, 10])
```